# Filter and get a new Map from ' Map<String,ProductItem>myMap' in dart

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a Map in dart as

```
Map<String, List<ProductItem>> _productItemsMap;
```

I want to filter and get a new `Map<String, List<ProductItem>> _newMap`
which has the Product Item's id the same as my condition. 
How can I do that in dart?
Thanks for you help.

Comment: can you add sample or possible value of _productItemsMap and expected result from it?

Comment: Now i have done it as in example of @jamesdlin below. Thanks for your help @ Viren V Varasadiya  :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are a few ways:

Use collection-for to create a new `Map` and use collection-if to filter:

```dart
var _newMap = {
  for (var entry in _productItemsMap.entries)
    if (satisfiesCondition(entry.key, entry.value))
      entry.key: entry.value,
};
```

Filter with `Iterable.where` and create a new `Map` with `Map.fromEntries`:

```dart
var _newMap = Map.fromEntries(_productItemsMap.entries
    .where((entry) => satisfiesCondition(entry.key, entry.value)));
```

Copy the `Map` first with `Map.of` and then remove the items you don't want:

```dart
var _newMap = Map.of(_productItemsMap)
  ..removeWhere((key, value) => !satisifiesCondition(key, value));
```